# .ExecuteNonQuery not working in editing part of my vb

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
Public Class frmEdit


Public connstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" & System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\oopdb.accdb"
Public conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Sub loadListView()
    With ListView1
        .FullRowSelect = True
        .MultiSelect = False
        .View = View.Details
        .Columns.Clear()
        .Items.Clear()
        .Columns.Add("Router ID", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Serial", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Model", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Remarks", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("DateChecked", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    End With

    With ListView2
        .FullRowSelect = True
        .MultiSelect = False
        .View = View.Details
        .Columns.Clear()
        .Items.Clear()
        .Columns.Add("Switch ID", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Serial", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Model", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Ports", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Remarks", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("DateChecked", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    End With

    With ListView3
        .FullRowSelect = True
        .MultiSelect = False
        .View = View.Details
        .Columns.Clear()
        .Items.Clear()
        .Columns.Add("Cable ID", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Type", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Model", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Remarks", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("DateChecked", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    End With

    With ListView4
        .FullRowSelect = True
        .MultiSelect = False
        .View = View.Details
        .Columns.Clear()
        .Items.Clear()
        .Columns.Add("Device ID", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Type", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Model", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Remarks", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("DateChecked", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    End With

    With ListView5
        .FullRowSelect = True
        .MultiSelect = False
        .View = View.Details
        .Columns.Clear()
        .Items.Clear()
        .Columns.Add("Monitor ID", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Serial", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Model", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Size", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Remarks", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("DateChecked", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    End With

    With ListView6
        .FullRowSelect = True
        .MultiSelect = False
        .View = View.Details
        .Columns.Clear()
        .Items.Clear()
        .Columns.Add("CPU ID", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Serial", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Model", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Remarks", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("DateChecked", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    End With

    Dim sqlq1 As String = "SELECT * FROM Router"
    Dim sqlq2 As String = "SELECT * FROM Switch"
    Dim sqlq3 As String = "SELECT * FROM Cables"
    Dim sqlq4 As String = "SELECT * FROM Devices"
    Dim sqlq5 As String = "SELECT * FROM Monitor"
    Dim sqlq6 As String = "SELECT * FROM CPU"

    Dim sqlcomm1 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim sqlcomm2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim sqlcomm3 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim sqlcomm4 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim sqlcomm5 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim sqlcomm6 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    Dim sqladpt1 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sqladpt2 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sqladpt3 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sqladpt4 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sqladpt5 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sqladpt6 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    Dim table1 As New DataTable
    Dim table2 As New DataTable
    Dim table3 As New DataTable
    Dim table4 As New DataTable
    Dim table5 As New DataTable
    Dim table6 As New DataTable

    With sqlcomm1
        .CommandText = sqlq1
        .Connection = conn
    End With
    With sqlcomm2
        .CommandText = sqlq2
        .Connection = conn
    End With
    With sqlcomm3
        .CommandText = sqlq3
        .Connection = conn
    End With
    With sqlcomm4
        .CommandText = sqlq4
        .Connection = conn
    End With
    With sqlcomm5
        .CommandText = sqlq5
        .Connection = conn
    End With
    With sqlcomm6
        .CommandText = sqlq6
        .Connection = conn
    End With

    With sqladpt1
        .SelectCommand = sqlcomm1
        .Fill(table1)
    End With
    With sqladpt2
        .SelectCommand = sqlcomm2
        .Fill(table2)
    End With
    With sqladpt3
        .SelectCommand = sqlcomm3
        .Fill(table3)
    End With
    With sqladpt4
        .SelectCommand = sqlcomm4
        .Fill(table4)
    End With
    With sqladpt5
        .SelectCommand = sqlcomm5
        .Fill(table5)
    End With
    With sqladpt6
        .SelectCommand = sqlcomm6
        .Fill(table6)
    End With

    For i = 0 To table1.Rows.Count - 1
        With ListView1
            .Items.Add(table1.Rows(i)("ID"))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(table1.Rows(i)("Serial"))
                .Add(table1.Rows(i)("Model"))
                .Add(table1.Rows(i)("Remarks"))
                .Add(table1.Rows(i)("DateChecked"))
            End With

        End With
    Next
    For i = 0 To table2.Rows.Count - 1
        With ListView2
            .Items.Add(table2.Rows(i)("ID"))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(table2.Rows(i)("Serial"))
                .Add(table2.Rows(i)("Model"))
                .Add(table2.Rows(i)("Ports"))
                .Add(table2.Rows(i)("Remarks"))
                .Add(table2.Rows(i)("DateChecked"))
            End With

        End With
    Next
    For i = 0 To table3.Rows.Count - 1
        With ListView3
            .Items.Add(table3.Rows(i)("ID"))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(table3.Rows(i)("Type"))
                .Add(table3.Rows(i)("Remarks"))
                .Add(table3.Rows(i)("DateChecked"))
            End With

        End With
    Next
    For i = 0 To table4.Rows.Count - 1
        With ListView4
            .Items.Add(table4.Rows(i)("ID"))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(table4.Rows(i)("Type"))
                .Add(table4.Rows(i)("Model"))
                .Add(table4.Rows(i)("Remarks"))
                .Add(table4.Rows(i)("DateChecked"))
            End With

        End With
    Next
    For i = 0 To table5.Rows.Count - 1
        With ListView5
            .Items.Add(table5.Rows(i)("ID"))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(table5.Rows(i)("Serial"))
                .Add(table5.Rows(i)("Model"))
                .Add(table5.Rows(i)("Size"))
                .Add(table5.Rows(i)("Remarks"))
                .Add(table5.Rows(i)("DateChecked"))
            End With

        End With
    Next
    For i = 0 To table6.Rows.Count - 1
        With ListView6
            .Items.Add(table6.Rows(i)("ID"))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(table6.Rows(i)("Serial"))
                .Add(table6.Rows(i)("Model"))
                .Add(table6.Rows(i)("Remarks"))
                .Add(table6.Rows(i)("DateChecked"))
            End With

        End With
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub frmView_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    conn.ConnectionString = connstring

    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Open()
    End If

    loadListView()

End Sub
Dim id As Integer
Private Sub ListView1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseClick
    Dim sqlquery1 As String = "SELECT * FROM Router"
    Dim sqlcom1 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim sqladpt1 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim t1 As New DataTable

    With sqlcom1
        .CommandText = sqlquery1
        .Connection = conn
    End With
    With sqladpt1
        .SelectCommand = sqlcom1
        .Fill(t1)
    End With

    If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count Then
        id = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text


     roserial.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
            romodel.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
            roremarks.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text
            rodate.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListView2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView2.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim sqlquery2 As String = "SELECT * FROM Switch"
        Dim sqlcom2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim sqladpt2 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim t2 As New DataTable

        With sqlcom2
            .CommandText = sqlquery2
            .Connection = conn
        End With
        With sqladpt2
            .SelectCommand = sqlcom2
            .Fill(t2)
        End With

        If ListView2.SelectedItems.Count Then
            id = ListView2.SelectedItems(0).Text
            swserial.Text = ListView2.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
            swmodel.Text = ListView2.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
            swport.Text = ListView2.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text
            swremarks.Text = ListView2.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text
            swdate.Text = ListView2.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(5).Text
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListView3_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView3.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim sqlquery3 As String = "SELECT * FROM Cables"
        Dim sqlcom3 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim sqladpt3 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim t3 As New DataTable

        With sqlcom3
            .CommandText = sqlquery3
            .Connection = conn
        End With
        With sqladpt3
            .SelectCommand = sqlcom3
            .Fill(t3)
        End With

        If ListView3.SelectedItems.Count Then
            id = ListView3.SelectedItems(0).Text
            caserial.Text = ListView3.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
            caremarks.Text = ListView3.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
            cadate.Text = ListView3.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListView4_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView4.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim sqlquery4 As String = "SELECT * FROM Devices"
        Dim sqlcom4 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim sqladpt4 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim t4 As New DataTable

        With sqlcom4
            .CommandText = sqlquery4
            .Connection = conn
        End With
        With sqladpt4
            .SelectCommand = sqlcom4
            .Fill(t4)
        End With

        If ListView4.SelectedItems.Count Then
            id = ListView4.SelectedItems(0).Text
            devtype.Text = ListView4.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
            devmodel.Text = ListView4.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
            devremarks.Text = ListView4.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text
            devdate.Text = ListView4.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListView5_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView5.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim sqlquery5 As String = "SELECT * FROM Monitor"
        Dim sqlcom5 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim sqladpt5 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim t5 As New DataTable

        With sqlcom5
            .CommandText = sqlquery5
            .Connection = conn
        End With
        With sqladpt5
            .SelectCommand = sqlcom5
            .Fill(t5)
        End With

        If ListView5.SelectedItems.Count Then
            id = ListView5.SelectedItems(0).Text
            monser.Text = ListView5.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
            monmod.Text = ListView5.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
            monsize.Text = ListView5.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text
            monrem.Text = ListView5.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text
            mondate.Text = ListView5.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(5).Text
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListView6_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView6.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim sqlquery6 As String = "SELECT * FROM CPU"
        Dim sqlcom6 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim sqladpt6 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim t6 As New DataTable

        With sqlcom6
            .CommandText = sqlquery6
            .Connection = conn
        End With
        With sqladpt6
            .SelectCommand = sqlcom6
            .Fill(t6)
        End With

        If ListView6.SelectedItems.Count Then
            id = ListView6.SelectedItems(0).Text
            cpser.Text = ListView6.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
            cpmod.Text = ListView6.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
            cprem.Text = ListView6.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text
            cpdate.Text = ListView6.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        Try
            Dim sqlquer1 As String = "UPDATE Router SET Serial = '" & roserial.Text & "', Model = '" & romodel.Text & "', Remarks = '" & roremarks.Text & "', DateChecked = '" & rodate.Text & "', WHERE ID = " & id & ""
            Dim sqlcom1 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

            With sqlcom1
                .CommandText = sqlquer1
                .Connection = conn
                .ExecuteNonQuery()

            End With
            MsgBox("UPDATE SUCCESSFUL")
            loadListView()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim sqlquer2 As String = "UPDATE Switch SET Serial = '" & swserial.Text & "', Model = '" & swmodel.Text & "',Ports = '" & swport.Text & "', Remarks = '" & swremarks.Text & "', DateChecked = '" & swdate.Text & "', WHERE ID = " & id & ""
            Dim sqlcom2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

            With sqlcom2
                .CommandText = sqlquer2
                .Connection = conn
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            MsgBox("UPDATE SUCCESSFUL")
            loadListView()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            Dim sqlquer3 As String = "UPDATE Cables SET Type = '" & caserial.Text & "', Remarks = '" & caremarks.Text & "', DateChecked = '" & cadate.Text & "', WHERE ID = " & id & ""
            Dim sqlcom3 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

            With sqlcom3
                .CommandText = sqlquer3
                .Connection = conn
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            MsgBox("UPDATE SUCCESSFUL")
            loadListView()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Try
            Dim sqlquer4 As String = "UPDATE Devices SET Type = '" & devtype.Text & "', Model = '" & devmodel.Text & "', Remarks = '" & devremarks.Text & "', DateChecked = '" & devdate.Text & "', WHERE ID = " & id & ""
            Dim sqlcom4 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

            With sqlcom4
                .CommandText = sqlquer4
                .Connection = conn
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            MsgBox("UPDATE SUCCESSFUL")
            loadListView()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Try
            Dim sqlquer5 As String = "UPDATE Monitor SET Serial = '" & monser.Text & "', Model = '" & monmod.Text & "',Size = '" & monsize.Text & "', Remarks = '" & monrem.Text & "', DateChecked = '" & mondate.Text & "', WHERE ID = " & id & ""
            Dim sqlcom5 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

            With sqlcom5
                .CommandText = sqlquer5
                .Connection = conn
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            MsgBox("UPDATE SUCCESSFUL")
            loadListView()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Try
            Dim sqlquer6 As String = "UPDATE CPU SET Serial = '" & cpser.Text & "', Model = '" & cpmod.Text & "', Remarks = '" & cprem.Text & "', DateChecked = '" & cpdate.Text & "', WHERE ID = " & id & ""
            Dim sqlcom6 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

            With sqlcom6
                .CommandText = sqlquer6
                .Connection = conn
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            MsgBox("UPDATE SUCCESSFUL")
            loadListView()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is where editing part is supposed to happen. I tried searching for answers, none of them seamed to work. I don't know why I keep getting an error with ".ExecuteNonQuery()" part.

Comment: The code you posted has SIX "ExecuteNonQuery".  It would really help if you indicated which line produces the error. And how about sharing the error code AND the exact error message?

Comment: all six of them produces the same errors..when i remove them the program runs but doesn't write anything on the database..

Comment: This can be closed as "typo" or "missing an [mcve]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the last comma that preceeds the "WHERE" clause

Comment: thanks a ton, Wayne.. removed it and my program now runs smoothly.. :)